# Rollback Issue - Liquibase

Tags: java, spring, maven, liquibase, jhipster

I'm trying to do some rollback functions through terminal. I'm using Maven and Liquibase for my JHipster project.

I'm trying to tag database versions and at some time to do rollback on specific version by tag. Here is my liquibase configuration file (master - databasechangelog):

```
...(some change sets that alter tables, load data etc.)...

<!-- Tag database version 1.0 -->
<changeSet id="version1" author="jhipster">
    <tagDatabase tag="version_1_0" />
</changeSet>
<!-- Version 1.0 ends here -->

<!-- Version 2.0 starts here -->
<include file="../../config/liquibase/changelog/20170123151950_added_column_to_table.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
```

New changelog file looks like this:

```
<changeSet id="20170123151950" author="jhipster">

    <addColumn tableName="sometable">
        <column name="somecolumn" type="varchar(32)"/>
    </addColumn>

</changeSet>
```

I have tried commands:

> mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackTag=version_1_0

and

> mvn liquibase:rollbackSQL -Dliquibase.rollbackTag=version_1_0

but nothing happened.

Does anyone have an idea how to rollback to previous version of database?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your maven command looks correct. What does databasechangelog table look like? does it have entries for your changes previous to the tag, for the tag and for the change after the tag? Worth noting that the rollback doens't always work out of the box, and you may have to specifiy the <rollback> within the changeSet in some cases. But for your case (addColumn) it should work automatically without specifying the <rollback> (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html)

Comment: my databasechangelog table has three rows. First is for creating table, second for tagging a database to version 1.0 and third for adding new column.

Comment: What version of maven and liquibase plugin are you using? What is the output you get when you run the maven command? Try verbose output. Also it might be worth trying a few things like using `rollbackCount` instead of `rollbackTag` or using an explicit rollback changeset (examples here: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html)

Comment: Maven version is: 3.3.9 ;   
Liquibase version is: 3.4.2;

I have already tried rollbackCount, it just output BUILD SUCCESS but nothing happened with database. Same thing is with rollbackTag. Really strange.

Comment: Looks fairly recent. Worth trying maven versbose option `-X` to see what's happening behind the scene

Comment: Here is the verbose output: 

http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0KBQ6

Comment: output doesn't look complete

Comment: here is the rest of output: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0KBQB

Comment: Maven debug messages don't seem to tell much. Try enabling liquibase debug messages by `-Dliquibase.logging=debug` (you can now remove `-X`)

Comment: to run mvn liquibase:rollbackSQL -Dliquibase.rollbackTag="version_1_0" -Dliquibase.logging=debug?

Comment: Nothing new I think: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0KBRZ

Comment: It's really hard to know anything from logs... This is really strange situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134696/discussion-between-taoufik-mohdit-and-heril-muratovic).

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem and my changelogFile uses the *include* tag to import other changelogs.

I found out that it fails silently when the filename column on your databasechangelog didn't match the filename where your script rollback is happening.

I'm running on liquibase version 3.5.3 and running the rollback thru maven

Answer (score 1):

you must add the rollback command to changeset :
for example :

```
<rollback>
           <dropColumn 
            columnName="somecolumn"
            tableName="sometable"/>
        </rollback>
```

Comment: have you tried    <goal>tag</goal> in your maven plugin configuration ?

Comment: Here is my maven-liquibase plugin configuration: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0TY9H

Comment: everything seems ok, 
have you tried to see if rollback count works or not ?
And after rollback before re-running your code check if the database has changed or not.
sorry I can't help more

Comment: rollbackCount also not working :( and nothing happens in database.